# Sitefinity - AutoGenerated Fields - Not persisting values

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity, sitefinity-feather

I'm exploring the use of the autogenerated fields in SiteFinity widget designers.

The fields are generated as expected. However, the selected values aer not persisted to the model. I.e. the `FAQs` property remains null after selecting in the widget designer.

What steps have I missed?
Do I need to implement my own angularJS controller?

Here's my model:

```
    public class CustomWidgetModel: CustomDynamicContentModelBase, IDynamicContentBase
    {
        [Content(Type = "Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.FAQs.Faq", AllowMultipleItemsSelection =true)]
        public MixedContentContext FAQs { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(WidgetDisplay.AllPublished)]
        public WidgetDisplay WidgetDisplay { get; set; }

        [Browsable(false)]
        public override string ContentTypeFullName => "Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.FAQs.Faq";

}
```

Comment: do you have any custom designer code?

Comment: solved, the properties need to be on the controller. it's a known bug: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/autogenerated-field-types-linkmodel-is-not-persisted

Comment: no, I am using this to test out autogenerated fields and widget designer editors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/linkmodel-is-not-persisted-if-it-is-in-the-model

It's a known bug, the property needs to be on the controller itself.